# Calculation of a limit related to integrals and the trapezoidal rule

Tags: limits, functions, derivatives, definite-integrals, continuity

Let $f \in [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be 2 times differentiable function, with continuous second derivative. Compute $\lim_{n \to \infty} n(n( \int_{0}^{1} f(x) \ dx -  \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n} f(\frac{k}{n}))-\frac{f(0)-f(1)}{2} )$ .

The first thing I noticed was that the limit terms in the big bracket is $0$, as you can see from this idea in this link [Limit of a Riemann Sum and Integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/914240/42969) , with $\lim_{n \to \infty}n( \int_{0}^{1} f(x) \ dx -  \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n} f(\frac{k}{n}))=\frac{f(0)-f(1)}{2}$, but further I don't know how to continue.If someone could help me I would be grateful.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4562778/72031